# Unable to convert data to micro seconds in Databricks SQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks, databricks-sql, aws-databricks

I have a requirement to convert a string to a timestamp, specifically in microsecond format. However, I am currently unable to convert it to microsecond precision. I can only convert the data up to millisecond precision.

```
%sql
select to_timestamp('06-24-2019 12:01:19.944678','M-d-y HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS')
```

I am getting Null output from the above query.